# Usage log analysis

Tags: java, log-analysis

I'm developing a RESTful API with java and want to have usage statistics.
so i've set a filter that log all authenticated request in a defined format, it currently simply writes the data to a day rolling file.

i want to have an administration panel to analyze and get data from this log such as how many request were made by specific user.

the best thing i can think of is to have a JAVA api to fetch the data i need,
is there an open source or a good framework that can be handy or the best way is to develop something myself?

Comment: I wrote something similar this summer. What I did was to use apache camel for reading, processing the file and persisting the raw data into a DB. Then designed a REST API for fetching real time statistics from the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at GrayLog2, it is open source free logger that can do more then basic reports of your log data.
GrayLog2 reads the logs from Apache elastic-search, you can populate from flume or using Log4J adapter.